# Why can't I set the template-url for uib-carousel dynamically?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to override the template-url for the uib-carousel directive, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/carousel/docs, however I can't get it to work unless using a 'hard-coded' string.

Overriding the template-url like this works

`<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="1000" no-wrap="false" template-url="path/to/template.html">`

But not like this

`<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="1000" no-wrap="false" template-url="dynamicTemplate">`

https://plnkr.co/edit/MPQs9lr7V7gyX21cB0bZ?p=preview

In the project I'm working on I'm using bootstrap without templates and an absolute url for the template but the plunker demonstrates the problem.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks
.r